Using BAAI/bge-small-en-v1.5 with ChromaDb and LlamaIndex
I am new to LLMs. I created a local RAG using Llamaindex with llama3 to load our documents and I am using ChromaDb to persist the embeddings. I am not clear on how do I specify a specific embedding model like BAAI/bge-small-en-v1.5 to be used to create embeddings instead of the default all-MiniLM-L6-v2 that Chroma DB uses. Here is my code:
import chromadb
from llama_index.vector_stores.chroma import ChromaVectorStore
from llama_index.core.storage import StorageContext
from llama_index.core.indices import VectorStoreIndex

db = chromadb.PersistentClient(path="<Folder path>")
chroma_collection = db.get_or_create_collection("myCollection")

vector_store = ChromaVectorStore(chroma_collection=chroma_collection)
storage_context = StorageContext.from_defaults(vector_store=vector_store)
index = VectorStoreIndex.from_documents(documents=documents, storage_context=storage_context)

I did set the embedding model on the Llamindex's Settings class like below:
from llama_index.core.settings import Settings

Settings.embed_model = HuggingFaceEmbedding(model_name="BAAI/bge-small-en-v1.5")

I don't see get_or_create_collection function referencing the above setting. I see a paramter "embedding_function" on the get_or_create_collection function call, by default it uses all-MiniLM-L6-v2. How do I set to use BAAI/bge-small-en-v1.5? If there is a better way to do this, please let me know as well.

This looks correct to me. Settings.embed_model is the right way of configuring your custom embed model. What is not working for you?

I thought that LlamaIndex was sending the documents to ChromaDB API to create the embeddings but upon looking into the LlamaIndex code and I saw that LlamaIndex is creating the embeddings and passing it to ChromaDB to store.  So, no need to specify embedding_function on ChromeDb. It was just my misunderstanding and everything is working as expected.
